# I need to pass token value from my home controller to account controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting data in json and passing these values to my `account` controller from `home` controller. I also have a token value in my `home` controller that I need in my `account` controller.

I am adding the code below (`HomeController` Code):

```
public JsonResult ProfileInfo(string token)
{
    var clienta = new RestClient("https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/tokeninfo?access_token="+token);
    var requestb = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    requestb.AddHeader("postman-token", "efe6939a-95b0-5ffc-f4a0-e462479e87ad");
    requestb.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    IRestResponse responseb = clienta.Execute(requestb);
//code for profile
    var client = new RestClient("https://api.amazon.com/user/profile");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    request.AddHeader("Host", "api.amazon.com");
    request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "3c733ec4-2336-4d5d-bb82-ab0993791bc5,d4a052f7-2a98-4b2a-b057-97511ce052b7");
    request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
    request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2");
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    return Json(response+responseb.Content, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here below is the `account` controller code :

```
// GET: /Account/Register
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register(long? token)
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return RedirectToLocal("/dashboard");
    }
    string email = "";
    string name = "";
    //token;
    if (Request.QueryString["email"] != null)
    {
         email = Request.QueryString["email"].ToString();
        email = email.Substring(1);
    }
    if (Request.QueryString["name"] != null)
    {
         name = Request.QueryString["name"].ToString();
        name = name.Substring(1);
    }
    @ViewBag.Email = email;
    @ViewBag.name = name;
    if (!token.HasValue)
        return RedirectToAction("Register", new
        {

            token = DateTime.Now.Ticks
        });

    return View();
}
```

I want to get that token value from my `home` controller to `account` controller. As it generates new token if it does not get token value from `home` controller.

Comment: TempData also works

Answer (score 1):

You can pass as a parameter set default is empty

In your home controller use this return statement this will redirection to the controller which is specified in ControllerName.

And in Account controller create action with parameter.
if you need that account in all activities of account controller use session

Assignment in session this way

```
     Session["testData"] = testData;
```

Access way

```
   var testData= (string)Session["testData"]



   return RedirectToAction("actionName", "ControllerName", new{ data: data})

   public ActionResult actionName(string data = "")
   {
     return View();
   }
```

Comment: use RedirectToAction to pass data from one controller to another